# Intersection of two open and simply connected is simply connected

Tags: general-topology

[Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-02/S0002-9939-1966-0188993-1/S0002-9939-1966-0188993-1.pdf), page $458$, in the proof of theorem $2$, there is this sentence

'Conversely, suppose $G=\bigcup_{i \geq 1}{U_i}$ where $U_i$ are open in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and simply connected. For each positive integer $n$, let $V_n=\bigcap_{i=1}^n{U_i}$ containing the connected $G$. It is easy to verify that each $V_n$ is simply connected.'

I don't understand why $V_n$ is simply connected. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: The intersection of 2 "fighting" crescents is not simply connected although each of them is.

Comment: there is a misprint, $G=\bigcap_{i \geq 1}{U_i}$.

Comment: and one more: $V_n$ is a _component_ of $\bigcap_{i=1}^nU_i$ containing $G$. so it is an answer for your question.